# How to run specific custom scripts on an AKS NodePool

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, node-pools

I have a provisioned AKS cluster with a default node pool set up.

I am creating a new node pool to run a specific set of workloads, is there a way to bootstrap the nodes created by this new nodepools with custom scripts.

EG:

```
NodePool - 1
yum install nginx
```

```
NodePool - 2
yum install httpd
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: In the specific example you show, I'd just run these as Kubernetes Deployments with corresponding Services; I wouldn't try to install anything directly on the node.  What do you need to install on the nodes?  Is there a programming aspect to this, or is this just a system-administration or DevOps issue?

Comment: This is unusual. Can you explain why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @CSharpRocks Maybe my approach is completely wrong here. I have an NFS sever that I would like to associate with all the nodes in a particular node pool. I also want the NFS server to be auto associated to any new nodes that get created in the same node pool.

Comment: @DavidMaze You make a valid point with regards to using Kubernetes Deployments. In my use case, it's to configure an NFS Server on a particular set of nodes. But now I'm wondering if PV's and PVC's might just be easier.

Comment: The pattern you describe would match a Kubernetes DaemonSet, but that's used much more often for things that collect or manage data specific to a node (for example, a log aggregator).  Does Azure have a hosted file service you can use here?  If you need to run it yourself, an in-cluster StatefulSet may be a better option (but I know NFS has some complexities, and I don't normally deal with this sort of system administration).